# How do I reshape tables?

Tags: python, pandas

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q | 1 | 2 |
| T | 5 | 6 |

I would like to reshape the table so that the columns B & C become the index and have the Q & T be the columns?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(columns='A')
```

output:

```
A  Q  T
B  1  5
C  2  6
```